# Amazon EC2 t1.micro + nginx + php-fpm = somtimes dead slow

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, php-fpm, gentoo

First something about the infrastructure:

We have migrated one of our backend/admin servers to amazon. The applications on this server are only used sporadically (max. 10 parallel users). We are using a t1.micro instance running Gentoo. As Webserver we are using nginx in combination with PHP-FPM. 
The problem is that sometimes the server is dead slow that means a page needs 10-20sec to load (max 2sec on my local dev environment, and these pages are heavy ... 80mb+). I tried to analyze and reproduce the error but only figured out the memory is okay (270mb free) while cpu load is at 100%

Configuration:

nginx has 2 workers and max. 1024 connections.

PHP-FPM (I removed the comments)

```
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm.log

...

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Pool Definitions ; 
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[www]

listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

user = www
group = www

pm = dynamic

pm.max_children = 8

pm.start_servers = 2

pm.min_spare_servers = 2

pm.max_spare_servers = 4

pm.max_requests = 100
```

I hope some one has a clue what to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html where you will find detailed information on t1.micro and how it comares to other instance types (like m1.small). It will help to understand the instance's behaviour.

Short: As soon as you exceed the "short burst" phase you will be getting a high amount of cpu 'st' (shown with `top`) which is slowing down everything.

Comment: We changed the instance type now everything works fine :)

Answer (score 3):

EC2 micro instances provide short bursts of CPU, not constant CPU power. This is the expected behavior. micro instances will only provide full CPU power for a few minutes at most then they limit it back to about 5-10% capacity. If you look in `top` you'll see a high value for 'st', this is CPU steal from the hypervisor (I.E. CPU you can't use/is thin provisioned).

> Instances of this family provide a small amount of consistent CPU
>   resources and allow you to burst CPU capacity when additional cycles
>   are available. They are well suited for lower throughput applications
>   and web sites that consume significant compute cycles periodically

-Amazon